# C++ #include, how does nested includes work?

Tags: c++, oop, include

So I'm learning C++ and learning to also use SQLite in my practices for data persistence across application runs, which is lots of fun.

But I bumped into this issue:

The program is a Grade Book, classic Ditel C++ book exercise. I'm structuring my classes as follows:

```
~/classes/Database.h/cpp // A small wrapper for sqlite3
~/classes/Student.h/cpp // The Student object with name and grades (Uses Database)
~/classes/GradeBook.h/cpp // Takes care of most of the application logic and UI (Uses Database and Student)
~/main.cpp // contains just the main function and base Instances of Database and GradeBook
```

This is so I can instantiate a Single Database Object from main() and pass it by reference to GradeBook and Student so they can use the Database functions. I tried all possible order of includes and as it turns out only this order has works for me.

```
Student includes Database.
GradeBook includes Student, gets access to Database.
main.cpp includes GradeBook, gets access to both Database and Student.
```

The question is, is this right? It seems utterly counter-intuitive that the includes seems to "cascade" backwards from deepest classes to the main.cpp file, in other words, Am I doing this right, or am I missing something?

If so, a little explanation or pointers on how this "cascading" works would be pretty awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: why does student use database? It looks like you can refine this so that gradebook uses database and student.

Comment: I want each Student object to be able to save its own data of comanded to do so from GradeBook

Comment: The design isn't sound. Why is student holding on to the database object? Consider this, database is for persistent storage. Student and GradeBook are snapshots of the persistent data, either taken from (without change) or to be stored into a database. Doesn't mean that the database instance should be known by those data. Ideally, database would be independent of the snapshot data. A snapshot data is 'loaded' from database using a utility function; either a static function in the class or a utility class. So who holds the database instance? Whoever manages loading Student and GradeBook.

Comment: You can embed that into the gradebook: take the value from student and save it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, your header files should use include guards to prevent multiple inclusion:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_H
#define MY_HDEADER_H

// code...

#endif  // this file will only ever be copied in once to another file
```

Secondly, you should explicitly include *all* of the header files that you need to do what you want to do.  Relying on header A to include header B for you is just clunky and, since you're using include guards, you never have to worry about including the same file twice.

So, to answer your question, no, it's not "right" in the sense that it could be "better".  `main.cpp` should include the all of the header files that it needs.  All of them.  `#include` is a simple text substitution mechanism.  When you `#include` a file it is literally pasted in.  That's it.

Comment: I think the main problem is determining actual needs. With your advice OP may adapt a bad habit of using excessive number of include statements.

Comment: @perreal: I disagree.  There is nothing "excessive" about including the files you need.  You should not be relying on one header to include another for you, you should be explicit.  There is no cost and your code is more robust because of it.  Don't rely on the current implementation of another header when there is no good reason to do so.  Also, with include guards it is a non-issue.

Comment: So, Another thing: Why if I import Database.h at the top of main.cpp it is not visible for Student whose import comes afterwards?

Comment: @JonathanAcosta: Again... *you should not be relying on including files for other files to consume*.  If `Student.h` needs `Database.h` then it should be including it.  If `main.cpp` needs `Database.h` then it should be including it as well. You are making things far more complicated than they need to be.  Look again at my include guard example.

Comment: To make the `#include` statement clear, it simply dumps the contents of the included file in that place. What the compiler compiles is ONLY the *.cpp files (or files that are marked as 'source' files). This means, the `#include` statement only makes sense when it can be seen by the CPP file. So, when you include `Database.h` in main.cpp, it is visible by the compiler when compiling main.cpp. When it compiles Student.cpp, which only includes Student.h, it dumps the all `#include`s and doesn't see Database.h in that list. Hence your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answers, your help is priceless :)